# Dice sums with 6 dice

Tags: probability-theory, dice

If we throw 8 dice and take the sum of the highest 4 outcomes, What is the probability that the sum equals to 24? 
I think in order to get sum 24, at least there are 4 times 6s among 8 dices. But how can i get the equation for this problem?

Comment: Look up the binomial distribution.  Each die has only two outcomes.  You have $1/6$ chance of a $6$ and $5/6$ chance of something else.  As you say, you need at least $4$ sixes.

Comment: Okey. but now i’m still confused what kind of equation i have to use. is it permutation?

Comment: @Aten As said: it is binomial distribution. To be found is $P(X\geq 4)$ where $X$ is the number of times a $6$ was thrown. The parameters of the distribution are $n=8$ and $p=1/6$.

Comment: ok thank you. I got it

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not require any knowledge of probability distributions. However I would suggest looking into it as it makes the problem much easier.

You need at least 4 sixes. Let's find the probability of obtaining exactly 4 sixes and you can do the rest. How many ways can you get exactly 4 sixes out of 8 dice? $8\choose 4$. What is the probability associated with each of these events? $(\frac 16)^4×(\frac56)^{8-4}$. Thus the probability of getting exactly 4 sixes is $8\choose 4$$(\frac16)^4(\frac56)^4$.

Find the probabilities of obtaining exactly 5,6,7,8 sixes in a similar fashion. Add them up. It should give you the answer.